# Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrix

I have a question about matrix multiplication. I have 3 matrix which are Ce matrix and its dimension is 3x3 . The second matrix is Be and it is 3x18x2  and the third matrix is del matrix and its dimension is 18x1.

I want to multiply three matrix as Ce . Be[[, , 1]] . del and Ce . Be [[, , 2] . del

If Be matrix is just 3x18 there is no problem but here its third dimension is 2 and I dont know how to multiply each of them. Could you help me ?

Best Regards;

Ahmet;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second matrix `be` has two pages. Each page is `3 by 18`, so when you multiply, just select the page you want to use. For example, to use the first page of `be`, then

```
ce = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 3}];
be = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 18, 2}]
del = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {18, 1}]
```

and now

```
ce.be[[All, All, 2]].del
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use the first page, do

```
ce.be[[All, All, 1]].del
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And to do all pages at once,

```
(ce.be[[All, All, #]].del) & /@ Range@Dimensions[be][[3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixForm[be[[All, All, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixForm[be[[All, All, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Transpose[ce.Transpose[be, {1, 3, 2}]].del` also works.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use TensorContract/TensorProduct:

```
ce=RandomInteger[{1,10},{3,3}];
be=RandomInteger[{1,10},{3,18,2}];
del=RandomInteger[{1,10},{18,1}];

(ce.be[[All,All,#]].del)&/@Range[2]
(* output: {{{5591},{12404},{10529}},{{4463},{10040},{8921}}} *)

Transpose[ce.Transpose[be,{1,3,2}]].del
(* {{{5591},{12404},{10529}},{{4463},{10040},{8921}}} *)

TensorContract[TensorProduct[be,ce,del],{{2,6},{1,5}}]
(* {{{5591},{12404},{10529}},{{4463},{10040},{8921}}} *)
```

Basically, `TensorProduct[be, ce, del]` has dimensions `{3,18,2,3,3,18,1}`, and the given `TensorContract` call eliminates (contracts) indices 1, 2, 5 and 6, leaving an array of dimensions `{2, 3, 1}`.